# cloudfoundry buildpack compilation failed

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I downloaded the cf java buildpack zip from https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack and unzipped it(on a windows 7 machine). I made some changes and created a custom buildpack by creating a zip file(By simply compressing to zip and not using buildpack packager). Now my app deployment is failing with error:

> 2017-05-23T15:14:03.19+0000 [STG/17] OUT -----> Downloaded app package (59M)
>   2017-05-23T15:14:03.36+0000 [STG/0] OUT Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
>   2017-05-23T15:14:03.36+0000 [STG/0] ERR
>   2017-05-23T15:14:03.46+0000 [API/0] ERR encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase

These are the only error logs even after setting CF_TRACE=true. Please suggest how to see more descriptive logs on buildpack compilation or any tool which may help in debugging.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I made some changes and created a custom buildpack by creating a zip file(By simply compressing to zip and not using buildpack packager).

Don't do that.  If you need a build pack to upload to your CF foundation, then use the instructions here to build a proper build pack.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/#building-packages

Brief Instructions:

1. Install Ruby
2. `git clone https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git`
3. `cd java-buildpack`
4. `git checkout <version>` ex: `git checkout v3.16`
5. `bundle install`
6. `bundle exec rake clean package` for a version without dependencies or `bundle exec rake clean package OFFLINE=true PINNED=true` for a version with dependencies.

**or**

If you don't need a build pack to upload and just want to test your changes then...

- Fork the Java build pack.
- Make your changes.
- Push them to your fork.
- Run `cf push -b <url-to-your-git-project>`.  Ex:  `cf push -b https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/java-buildpack`.

This will instruct the *single* app to use your copy of the build pack.  This will only work if your CF foundation has network access to the Git URL specified.

Hope that helps!